# SQL Server: SELECT IF conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with different columns and I need to show different based on the value of a specific column.

My table It's like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
from table1
```

So, for example:

if col1 = '1' --> show col3 and col4.

if col2 = '1' --> show col5 and col6

Comment: are columns 3,4,5 & 6 all the same data type?

Comment: In your expected output, what do you want to show? `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6` or just `col1, col2, colum_a, column_b` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `case` expressions to chose columns to return. Note that a case's return types must be compatible, i.e. col3 and col5, and col4 and col6.

```
select case when col1 = 1 then col3
            when col2 = 1 then col5
       end,
       case when col1 = 1 then col4
            when col2 = 1 then col6
       end
from tablename
```

Or, do a `UNION ALL`:

```
select col3, col4
from tablename where col1 = 1
union all
select col5, col6
from tablename where col2 = 1
```

Remaining questions - what do to if both col1 and col2 are 1? Or if none of them are?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb 1 : return to the caller the columns used for filtering.

Rule of thumb 2 : don't use `union all`, it returns duplicates and your result will not be a 'relation' (though in this case there would be no duplicates because col1 is a key but I still think `union` states the intent best).

```
select col1, col2, col3 AS colum_a, col4 AS colum_b
from table1
where col1 = 1
union
select col1, col2, col5 AS colum_a, col6 AS colum_b
from table1
where col2 = 1;
```

Comment: It's a key, so It can't happen that both are 1.

Comment: Columns are the same type, and the result will be:
col1, col2, colum_a, column_b